# Rule / equation for optimal screw diameter?

Tags: bolting, wood

Is there a rule / equation for the optimal screw diameter per wood thickness?

I have a 16mm baltic birch plywood,
I have two pices 30mmX20mmX16mm
I want to butt join them at their profile
What will be the optimal diameter for the 16mm?
The max diameter before the layers split to achieve max amount of bend strength

Comment: That sounds like asking for trouble if you are trying to withstand bending. Can you provide any form of wrap around reinforcement to prevent splitting on the tension side? Like glass wrap?

Comment: Not possible :(
I can add a thin aluminum profile 
Also a brass / aluminum tube

But it will add complexity and cost to the project